# Service workers slow speed when serving from cache

Tags: service-worker, html5-appcache

I have some resources that I want to be cached and served at top speed to my app.

When I used appcache I got great serving speeds, but i was stuck with an appcache.

So I've replaced it with a service worker.

Then I tried the simplest strategy, just cache the static assets on install and serve them from the cache whenever fetched.

It worked, when I checked chrome's network panel I was happy to see my service worker in action, BUT - the load times were horrible, each resource load time doubled.

So I started thinking about other strategies, [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/) you can find plenty of them, the cache and network race sounded interesting but i was deterred by the data usage.

So I've tried something different, I tried to aggressively cache the resources in the service worker's memory. Whenever my service worker is up and running it pools the relevant resources from the cache and save the response objects in memory for later use. When it gets a matching fetch it just responds with a clone of the in memory response.

This strategy proved to be fastest, here's a comparison I made:

[image: caching speed comparison]

So my question is pretty vague as my understanding in service workers is still pretty vague...

Does this all makes sense, can I keep static resources cache in memory?
What about the bloated memory usage, are there any negative implications in that? for instance - maybe the browser shuts down more frequently service workers with high memory consumption.

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely on keeping `Response` objects in memory inside of a service worker and then responding directly with them, for (at least) two reasons:

- Service workers have a short lifetime, and everything in the global scope of the service worker is [cleared](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/07/android-p-feature-spotlight-volume-buttons-change-media-volume-default-instead-ringer/) each time the service worker starts up again.
- You can only read the body of a `Response` object once. Responding to a `fetch` request with a `Response` object will cause its body to be read. So if you have two requests for the same URL that are both made before the service worker's global scope is cleared, using the `Response` for the second time will fail. (You can work around this by calling `clone()` on the `Response` and using the clone to respond to the `fetch` event, but then you're introducing additional overhead.)

If you're seeing a significant slowdown in getting your responses from the service worker back to your page, I'd take some time to dig into what your service worker code actually looks like—and also what the code on your client pages look like. If your client pages have their main JavaScript thread locked up (due to heavyweight JavaScript operations that take a while to complete and never yield, for instance) that could introduce a delay in getting the response from the service worker to the client page.

Sharing some more details about how you've implemented your cache-based service worker would be a good first step.

Comment: Regarding your first bullet, I know the global scope is cleared, under my implementation I load the resources to the memcache either at install time from the network or at startup time from the cache (initialization code runs outside of any function, in the worker global scope). Regarding your second bullet - as mentioned, I clone every response before I return it from the memory cache, its fine despite the cloning overhead. The client code is not at fault, fetching the resource from the cache is what's causing the additional overhead. Can't share my worker code at this time, its a mess.

Comment: My gut reaction is that the cost of loading the resources each time the service worker starts up is not going to be trivial, especially when it might need to happen relatively frequently, depending on how long your SW instances stay alive in between requests.

Comment: Any solution. I am facing slow content download issue with serviceworker